# multiple selection combo box

Tags: php

```
    ComBox1(Allows Multiple Selection)             ComboBox2
    __________________________________             __________

    Fruits                                         
    Vegetables
```

I have a combobox1(that allows multiple selection) that has the items: Fruits & vegetables.

The items in the ComboBox2 will be filled depending upon the selection based on the ComboBox1.

If "Fruits" is selected then the items in the ComboBox2 Should be: apple, orange,banana

```
    ComBox1(Allows Multiple Selection)             ComboBox2
    __________________________________             __________

    Fruits  (selected)                             Apple
    Vegetables                                     Orange
                                                   Banana
```

If both Fruits and vegetables, then ComboBox2 items should be: apple, orange, banana,radish, lettuce.

```
    ComBox1(Allows Multiple Selection)             ComboBox2
    __________________________________             __________

    Fruits  (selected)                             Apple
    Vegetables (selected)                          Orange
                                                   Banana
                                                   Radish
                                                   Lettuce
```

I need to do this using PHP. Can anyone suggest how this functionality can be achieved like using Jquery or ajax or javascript?

In reality i fetch the items in both combo boxes from the database.

Comment: Do you have any codes to start with or are you asking for the codes?

Comment: Posting some codes would be useful. Also explain what you're trying to do with the codes. Are you asking for help to modify it for multiple selection? If so post your current codes and your attempt in modifications and tell us what you expect them to do. If not, explain clearly what else you're asking for and post the relevant codes. This is a QA site on programming and placing some codes is the easiest way to get things started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery, include the jquery library

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

Then use the following script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#typeSelect').change(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url:"data.php",
    data: { type: $('#typeSelect').val() },
    type: "POST",
   }).success(function(data){
    $("#itemSelect").html(data);
   });
  });
 });
</script>
```

Using this form:

```
<form>
 <select id="typeSelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
  <option value="vege">Vegetables</option>
 </select>
 <select id="itemSelect" multiple="multiple">

 </select>
</form>
```

And in data.php you'd put:

```
<?php
$a = array(
 "fruit" => array(
  "apples" => "Apples",
  "bananas" => "Bananas", 
  "pears" => "Pears"
 ),
 "vege" => array(
  "toma" => "Tomatoes", 
  "cucu" => "Cucumber", 
  "rad" => "Radish"
 )
);

foreach($_POST['type'] as $type){
 foreach($a[$type] as $key => $val){
  echo "<option val='{$key}'>{$val}</option>";
 }
}
```

Ofcourse you'd fill the first selectbox with PHP, and generate the array based on the posted values, but for the purpose of showing how to fill the select boxes, I used an static array.