# How to change an option value in one field by changing the option value in another

Tags: javascript, php

Here's my code, my question will follow.

```
<tr>
    <td><h5>Race:</h5></td>
    <td class="top" colspan="2"><select name="race">
         <option value="empty_r">*Choose</option>
         <option value="Humans">Humans</option>
         <option value="Orcs">Orcs</option>
    </select><?php if (!empty($errors[7])) echo "$errors[7]"; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><h5>Faction:</h5></td>
    <td class="top" colspan="2"><select name="faction">
        <option value="empty_f">*Choose</option>
         <option value="Human_Faction1">Human Faction 1</option>
         <option value="Orc_Faction1">Orc Faction 1</option>
    </select><?php if (!empty($errors[8])) echo "$errors[8]"; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to make it so that when I choose humans as my race, only the human faction 1 will display in the faction select field. And if i choose Orcs as my race, only the orc faction 1 will display as an option. I tried to do this using just PHP but with no luck. I won't learn any javascript until this coming semester!

Comment: Have you tried anything already? This is more on using javascript.

Comment: You can't do this with PHP, it only runs when you submit the form, not dynamically in the browser.

Comment: Orcs and humans will have to wait till next semester, then, because using JavaScript is about the only way of solving your problem. At any rate, PHP isn't.

Comment: You either have to wait until next semester or learn Javascript on your own.

Comment: what about `JQuery`???

Comment: @ling.s That's Javascript.

Comment: Related work already done much times like this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621787/multiple-selection-combo-box`.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't see your comment before posting a comment

Comment: I think i may just have to create more option values in the faction selection that lists each faction as being orc or human, and if someone has their race set as humans and selects an orc faction, it will spit out an error message. I think that's my only solution until i learn javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function human_faction()
{
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML="   <option  value='empty_f'>*Choose</option> <option value='Human_Faction1'>Human Faction 1</option>";
}
function orcs_faction()
{
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML="   <option  value='empty_f'>*Choose</option> <option value='Orc_Faction1'>Orc Faction 1</option>";
}
</script>

<tr>
<td><h5>Race:</h5></td>
<td class="top" colspan="2"><select name="race">
<option value="empty_r">*Choose</option>
<option value="Humans" onclick="human_faction()">Humans</option>
<option value="Orcs" onclick="orcs_faction()">Orcs</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h5>Faction:</h5></td>
<td class="top" colspan="2"><select id="show" name="faction">
<option  value="empty_f">*Choose</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```